# Apache Settings For Unique subdomain and Domain Directories

Tags: apache, directory, subdomain, config

I'm fairly capable with most of the web server configuration but I have run into a problem.

I have a VPS install with one sub domain. Currently the link sub1.domain.com points to the root of the public_html/www folder.

I am now looking at creating new sub domains as well as using domain.com to point to a wordpress installation.

From my understanding, I must edit the apache httpd.conf file, but I am unsure exactly how to do this. I would expect that I would have to have domain.com point to a subdirectory as well as sub2.domain.com point to a different sub directory. Something like the following.

```
sub1.domain.com >> rootPathForApache/
domain.com >> rootPathForApache/domain.com/
sub2domain.com >> rootPathForApache/sub2/
```

Could somebody please point me in the right direction.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options:

**Option 1:** Apache's [`<VirtualHost>` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/) could solve this (multiple). This is only available in the [server config context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "rootPathForApache/"
    ServerName sub1.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "rootPathForApache/domain.com/"
    ServerName domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "rootPathForApache/sub2/"
    ServerName sub2domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

**Option 2:** Use a .htaccess file in `rootPathForApache` with the `mod_rewrite` module loaded, *and* introduce [`ServerAlias` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) into either your existing `<VirtualHost>` directive.

.htaccess contents (or if you want within the VirtualHost directive itself):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^sub1.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)           $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)           domain.com/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^sub2domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)           sub2/$1 [L]
```

...and the `ServerAlias`:

```
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias sub1.domain.com sub2domain.com
```

The latter solution (option 2) just seems ridiculous, especially since ServerAlias is only available within a VirtualHost directive and mod_rewritehtaccess files add unnecessary overhead. That and it doesn't seem natural. I guess it illustrates the flexibility of Apache's configuration and modules.